# MySQL Query - 2 Sums, added together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (orders) like this:

```
id
sub_total
final_total
status_id
date_estimated
```

I'm looking to do the following:  Every order with a `status_id = 65`, add up their `sub_total`s.  Every order with a `status_id > 65`, add up their `final_total`s.  Then, take both sums, add them together, and return this new sum.

Is this possible in one query?  Initially I had the following, but this doesn't account for the new `final_total` functionality:

```
"SELECT SUM(sub_total) as total 
   FROM orders 
  WHERE month(date_estimated) = month(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND status_id = 65"
```

nevermind the date stuff in this query.

Comment: how about `UNION`? Are there many values for status_id over 65?

Comment: No, they only go to 68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(sub_total) as total 
   FROM orders 
  WHERE month(date_estimated) = month(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND status_id = 65
UNION 
SELECT SUM(final_total) as total 
   FROM orders 
  WHERE month(date_estimated) = month(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND status_id > 65
```

Comment: Thsi is pretty close, but it returns the 2 results as 2 rows in the same column.  Is it possible to return the sum of the 2?